Do figured bass symbols indicate an altered octave?

This is notated in B♭ major and the ♭VII chord has a duplicate of its octave in one of the upper voices. Would this need a figured bass symbol?

No. Same as chord symbols, figured bass takes no notice of octave shift or doubling.
